# getting value of the maximum key in dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I only found here how can I get the key of the maximum value:

```
max(d, key=d.get())
```

but I need to search the maximum key and return the value of this key.

thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the maximum key

```
max(d)
```

And for the value, just look it up in the dictionary

```
d[max(d)]
```

Note: You can also use `max(d.keys())`, but it a bit slower because it needs to build a temporary list

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'd={x:str(x) for x in range(10000)}' 'max(d)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 377 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'd={x:str(x) for x in range(10000)}' 'max(d.keys())'
1000 loops, best of 3: 476 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `max(d.keys())` or equivalently simply `max(d)` (this is the better alternative).

Comment: In Python2, that will create a temporary list of the keys and then iterate over it. Better to just iterate over `d`

Answer (score 1):

max(d.values())  will give the largest value in the dictionary d